# Need help properly handling the state of recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get recyclerview to work how i want it to work. What i understand so far is that after a rv item is recycled if you're not handling the state properly it can lead to some surprises. so I have a recyclerview adapter that shows a question item. basically a combination of a textview for the question itself, and 5 checkboxes for the answers.

I'm changing the color of the answer text either green or red depending on whether it's right or wrong. The issue I'm facing is when the view recycles it goes back to it's default state. (Unchecked checkboxes and uncolored answers) I'd like to have it so that the changed state after revealing the answers stays. Take a look at my adapter class

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.jaytech.qcmvault.R
import com.jaytech.qcmvault.data.Question

class QuestionAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.QuestionViewHolder>() {
    var allQuestions = ArrayList<Question>()


    inner class QuestionViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val question:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_question)
        val answerA:CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerA)
        val answerB:CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerB)
        val answerC:CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerC)
        val answerD:CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerD)
        val answerE:CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answerE)

        val optionError: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionError)
        val correctButton:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.correctButton)
        val retryButton:Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.retryButton)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.question_item, parent, false)
        return QuestionViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return allQuestions.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.apply {
            optionError.visibility = View.GONE

            question.text = allQuestions[position].question
            answerA.text = allQuestions[position].answers[0]
            answerA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerA.isChecked = false

            answerB.text = allQuestions[position].answers[1]
            answerB.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerB.isChecked = false

            answerC.text = allQuestions[position].answers[2]
            answerC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerC.isChecked = false

            answerD.text = allQuestions[position].answers[3]
            answerD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerD.isChecked = false

            answerE.text = allQuestions[position].answers[4]
            answerE.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerE.isChecked = false

            val correctAnswers: List<Boolean> = allQuestions[position].correctAnswers
            val answersCheckboxList = arrayOf(answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, answerE)

            correctButton.setOnClickListener {
                for (i in answersCheckboxList.indices) {
                    val checkBox = answersCheckboxList[i]
                    val isCorrect = correctAnswers[i]

                    if (answerA.isChecked || answerB.isChecked || answerC.isChecked || answerC.isChecked || answerD.isChecked || answerE.isChecked) {
                        if (isCorrect) {
                            checkBox.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                            optionError.visibility = View.GONE

                        } else checkBox.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                    } else optionError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            retryButton.setOnClickListener {
                answersCheckboxList.forEach {
                    it.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                    it.isChecked = false
                }
                optionError.visibility = View.GONE

            }

        }
    }
}
```

here's my question class too

```
data class Question(
    val question:String?,
    val answers:List<String>,
    val correctAnswers:List<Boolean>
)
```

I tried manually handling the state like this

```
  answerA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerA.isChecked = false


  answerB.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerB.isChecked = false

  answerC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerC.isChecked = false

  answerD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerD.isChecked = false

  answerE.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            answerE.isChecked = false
```

I was expecting it to keep the views below from having an unwanted changed state. It works but what ends up happening is it resets the view item I interacted with which is not what i want. I want it to leave the ones I interact with and only act on those that I havent yet

Comment: You have to store checkbox state when check boxes are clicked (there are a few different ways to do this) and restore the check box state in ‘onBindViewHolder()` since this function is called every time a view scrolls onto the screen. There are many tutorials online for using check boxes in a recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `Question` data class itself to store the selected answer.

1. Create an integer field for storing the selected answer

   ```
   var selectedAnswer: Int
   ```
2. Use state change listener to save selected answer. For storing use can use 1,2,3 and 4 corresponding to answerA, answerB, answerC and answerD checkboxes respectively. You can also use String or enum to map this as per your choice.

   ```
   // do this for all check boxes with different values to selected answer
   answerA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                       if(isChecked)
                        allQuestions[position].selectedAnswer = 1
                    }
                }
        );
   ```
3. Get the value of selected answer in `onBindViewHolder` and manage the state of checkboxes accordingly

   ```
    when(allQuestions[position].selectedAnswer){
         1 -> answerA.setChecked = true
         2 -> answerB.setChecked = true
         3 -> answerC.setChecked = true
         4 -> answerD.setChecked = true
    }
   ```

If you have multiple options correct, type of questions, you can use an array to store selected answers instead of just an int variable.